# Bypass onclick event and after excuting some code resume onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below html button which have onclick event

```
<button onclick="alert('button');" type="button">Button</button>
```

and the following js:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    alert('jquery');
});
```

After executing some js code by jQuery/Javascript, i want to continue with the button onclick handler e.g: jquery alert first and than button alert.

i tried so many things like "remove attr and append it after executing my code and trigger click (it stuck in loop, we know why :) )" and "off" click. but no luck.

is it possible via jQuery/javascript?

any suggestion much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: is it necessary to do what you are trying to do? anything the html onclick can do, can also be done in .on(click with javascript/jquery

Comment: @Alexandros yes but the onclick code contain some parameter which is coming dyanamically through JSP.

Comment: @kpsingh You can pass the parameter using data attributes. `<button data-param="<%= paramValue %>"...`

Comment: any variables accessible from the `html onclick` are accessible from the `$('button').on('click', function(){..` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit tricky. http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/t4eAL/

```
$(function() {
    var button = $('#button'),
        onclick = button.attr('onclick'); //get onclick value;

    onclick = new Function(onclick); //manually convert it to a function (unsafe)

    button.attr('onclick', null); //clear onclick
    button.click(function() { //bind your own handler
        alert('jquery');
        onclick.call(this); //call original function
    })
});
```

Though there is a better way to pass params. You can use data attributes.

`<button data-param="<%= paramValue %>"...`

Comment: Thanks Yury. It's working as i expected and yes it is tricky code. By the way i am not a jsp guy and not able to change jsp file so better to do with jquery/javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate javascript function that contains what you want to do when the button is clicked (i.e. removing the onclick attribute and adding replacement code in its own function).

Then call that function at the end of

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    alert('jquery');
});
```

So you'll be left with something like this

```
function buttonFunction()
{
  //Do stuff here
}

$('button').on('click', function()
{
  alert('jquery');
  buttonFunction();
});

<button type="button">Button</button>
```

Comment: My bad, I didn't remove the OnClick from the button html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

http://jsfiddle.net/8a2FE/

`<button type="button" data-jspval="anything">Button</button>`

```
$('button').on('click', function () {

    var $this = $(this),                //store this so we only need to get it once
        dataVal = $this.data('jspval'); //get the value from the data attribute

    //this bit will fire from the second click and each additional click
    if ($this.hasClass('fired')) {

        alert('jquery'+ dataVal);
    }
    //this will fire on the first click only
    else {

        alert('button');

        $this.addClass('fired'); //this is what will add the class to stop this bit running again
    }

});
```

Comment: why if-else? i want both event but in reverse

Comment: @kpsingh the `if` is checking if the button has a css class of `fired` this class has been added in the `else`, so the first button press will run the `else`, then each additional press will run the `if`.